# Can I pretend I'm passing a different type of object to a function?

Tags: c++, templates, static, alignment, size

My question I guess applies to any case where you're accessing a structure through a generic pointer or casting.

I have a templated struct:

```
template <typename T> 
struct Buffer
{
    T buffer;          // <-- These will be various different structs of different data types
    // Perhaps some other members
};
```

Once I've instantiated one of these struct objects I'd like to pass it to a function. I know probably the correct way would be to make the function like:

```
void myFunc(Buffer<T>& buffer);
```

My understanding is that each time in my code I send another buffer object the template has to instantiate another version of this function, as the data inside will be different in each one. I guess another way is to make it generic through virtual functions, but I was wondering, if I were to make the generic function:

```
void myFunc(Buffer<int>& buffer);
```

Supposing I were careful about the alignment and positions of its members, could I then go:

```
void myFunc(Buffer<int>& buffer)
{
    // My buffer is the first member, the type is unknown but its size is known
    T or int buffer; // <--- and send this object off somewhere (sending its address?)

}
```

I could easily do it the other ways, but this crossed my mind and I was wondering if it's safe. Probably not advisable in any case. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question..

Comment: Are you trying to restrict/avoid instantiation of certain types ?

Comment: @Marco. A. Hahaha, OK. I totally get you.

Comment: Are you looking for a template function? `template <typename T> void myFunc(Buffer<T>& buffer){..}`

Comment: @P0W Well, I'm just a beginner, and seeing as though I won't know how many objects I'll make, and that template instantiation slows down compile times and adds to the executable (though by how much I don't know), it crossed my mind about how I could do things different. I liked Marco. A's comment, hahah.

Comment: @Simon Kraemer I though I had that there. I was just wondering if it was safe or OK to do. I can see all of you are confused as hell about why I'd wonder this. I'm just curious.

Comment: I think have to join the "I don't understand the question.." group of people. Are you talking about interpreting any type `Buffer<T>` as `Buffer<int>`?

Comment: @ISimon Kraemer I'm basically saying for example if I were to cast the int version to a void pointer in the function and send its address, being the first member it "should" be exactly the same thing no matter what it pointed to. However if it had for example an int or a char as the first members before the buffer, and then a long long as the first member of the buffer, then it would be pointing to different memory. But being the first member it's safe?

Comment: @TitoneMaurice Probably go through [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232397) first ?

Answer (score 1):

"My understanding is that each time in my code I send another buffer object the template has to instantiate another version of this function"

"seeing as though I won't know how many objects I'll make"

I think perhaps you are expecting a cost for each *instance* that you send to the function - or each time you call the function. Ignoring inlining for now, be aware that there is only a cost for each *type* you send to the function. If your app sends 100 `Buffer<int>`s in 5 different places in the code, and 200 `Buffer<char>`s in 1 place, and 30 `Buffer<std::string>`s in 30 places - there are only 3 instantiations of the function.

---

Edit after reading 1st comment:

If you function is passing these structs to a graphics card (or API, etc) it is quite possible that the "business end" of you code really just wants to pass the address and size of the struct somewhere. If it is as simple as something like this (psuedo-ish code)

```
template <typename Buffer>
void myFunc(Buffer& buffer) {
    send_to_gfx(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
}
```

Then it doesn't matter how many thousands of these you instantiate. They will all be inlined away to direct calls to `send_to_gfx`. (This, of course, assumes that `send_to_gfx` expects a `void*` pointer for its first parameter.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually the bit between the angled brackets will be structs, consisting of for example {vec4, float, int}, and they'll all be different, to send to the graphics card.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice - there are only a few tens of types that a graphics card (or API) expects. Even if you are also passing parameters to custom shaders in this way, you probably only have a handful of shaders. The total number of types (`struct{vec4, float, int}` is 1 type) you have is probably small enough to not worry about.

Comment: Yeah true. I'm just getting into OpenGL and I really don't know how to go about things. It really is all too much for one guy, I usually spend the entire day trying to find the answer to one thing just to make an inch of progress. I need to go to school.